# Java sum of numbers error

Tags: java

This code seems to run well, but am getting error message regarding calculating the sum of the integers entered.

The point of the exercise is to input a series of numbers, and after the value -1 is entered, calculate the sum of the numbers, how many numbers were entered, the mean value, and the number of odd and even numbers.

The output I get suggests the program is running fine, but still get an eror message.

With input `1 17 2 18 17 -1` should print `"sum: 55" expected:<55> but was: <0>`

Apologies in advance if my Java syntax is a bit inelegant. I'm fairly new at this! Code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopsEndingRemembering {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Type numbers: ");
        int n;
        double sum = 0.0;
        int i = 0;
        double average = 0.0;
        int odd = 0;
        int even = 0;

        while (true) {
            n = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

            if (n != -1) {
                System.out.print("Type numbers: ");
                sum += n;
                i++;
                average = sum / i;
                if (n % 2 == 0) {
                    even++;
                } else {
                    odd++;
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");
                System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
                System.out.println("How many numbers: " + i);
                System.out.println("Average: " + average);
                System.out.println("Even numbers: " + even);
                System.out.println("Odd numbers: " + odd);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the exercise wants you to print "sum:<55>", but you are printing "The sum is 55".

Comment: You don't need to calculate the average each time. Add the statement `average = sum / i;` into the `else` portion

Comment: it would says 55.0 look properly !

Comment: Just ran this on my box and got 55.0 for Sum.

Comment: This code works fine

Comment: How are you inputting the numbers i.e single line vs multiple lines?

Comment: You should show us your test class.

Comment: Ususally those types of tasks (uploaded to evaluation system) are supposed to have pre-defined format of input and output, otherwise the test class generates an exception. What were the requirements?

Comment: You're not typing all the numbers at once are you?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. This is a reasonable question regarding an uncooperative test case.

Comment: The input is in multiple lines after the prompt, 'Type numbers: ' into System.out.print("Type numbers: ");

Comment: The comments and suggestions given already (very quick!) have been very helpful! Thank you.

Comment: The code now runs well, and no error messages. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing `55.0`.  It seems you're getting this program tested by another program which you don't have access to the source code of.

**Issue 1**

You probably want to print `55` specifically.

Instead of:

```
double sum = 0.0;
```

Do:

```
int sum = 0;
```

**Issue 2**

Use `int` over `double`.  Cast to `double` for the `average` value.

Then instead of this:

```
average = sum / i;
```

Do something like:

```
average = (double)sum / i;
```

**Issue 3**

Also, it seems the error message wants you to print as `sum: 55`.

So change this:

```
System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```

To:

```
System.out.println("sum: " + sum);
```